# Which is better comparing iPhone and Android?

Tags: iphone, android, ios4

I am iPhone application developer, many people told me to join with the android application development, as it's future is far better comparing to iphone.

As I am iPhone developer, I prefers to be stay with iPhone , but in reality is it true that android is being far better comparing to iPhone ??

I can't say as I've never done android programming, so any one can tell me who's applications are better in all aspects?

Comment: Voting to close as subjective and argumentative.

Comment: Agreed. There is no "right" answer to this question, only speculative discussion.

Comment: Still If sum one having two choices, either select android programming or iPhone than which is preferable? ? ?

Comment: @iPhone Fun - depends on a lot of factors. Knowing none of them, it's only a subjective flame fest.

Comment: @EFraim +1 for the 'flame fest'. lol

Comment: iPhone OS and Android should be

Comment: Don't close. While there is probably no way to find out which one is better, or even to agree what "better" means in this context, comparisons can be made, both objective and subjective. Those are useful, for example for me who is thinking about learning Android development.

Comment: Also, this same question comes up every few weeks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381759/iphone-or-android , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932522/iphone-vs-android , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872118/developing-for-iphone-or-android-as-a-c-developer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one that fits you best.

I prefer developing on Android because I'm against Apple's TOS.

You may prefer working on iPhone because you love Objective-C.

The next one may tell you he loves both because he loves the design of iPhone frameworks but also loves Java.

Summing up, this is subjective.

EDIT
Some quick facts:

- Android runs on lots of devices, not just one 'series'.
- Android is open
- iPhone application approval is more strict, so, usually, crap application wouldn't reach the AppStore. This may be good for iPhone users
- AndroidMarket subscription cost 25$ una tantum, iPhone AppStore, if I remember well, is at least 99$ per year

Take your conlcusions on this few facts (I'm sure you can't...)

Answer (score 2):

If you feel comfortable with iPhone, than stay with iPhone. If you want to expand your skill set, then learn Android. Beyond that, it doesn't really matter. All the iPhones aren't going to suddenly evaporate (no matter how much Google would like that), and all of the Android phones aren't going to spontaneously combust (as much as Apple would like).

Answer (score 2):

There is no sensible way to say either is technically “better” than the other. They are both modern development environments.

When talking about developing for Android vs iOS, the critical difference is not usually technical, but business. On Android you can develop outside of the App Store model and the restrictions on being in the Store are generally considered less onerous. On iPhone/iPad, you may only make applications available through iTunes.

This makes iOS developers dependent on Apple's permission to ship applications, and there have been a number of high profile complaints from authors who have had their application's approval delayed or denied on what seem to be spurious and capricious grounds. This has made a number of developers critical of Apple, and supportive of a more open development platform. They see Android as the best chance of unseating Apple's current dominance of the smartphone market, which is why advocates push Android as ‘a better future’.

(And maybe they're right.)

Answer (score 1):

Having tried both development environments, there are several things to take into account. The pros of iPhone are

1. Easy download and install of SDK and IDE (XCode)
2. One screen size (or two as you need to develop for iPod touch as well)
3. A single market place: AppStore

the pros of Android are

1. Basic techniques. You don't have
   to learn a whole new programming
   language (Java + XML)
2. Don't have
   to follow and comply with Human
   Interface Guidelines
3. Easier to
   upload to market, since you're in
   control (and responsible). Don't
   have to wait for up to 90 days
   before your app is visible
4. Can
   install your app on a real device
   without any cost
5. Don't have to
   use the Android Market for
   distribution. Build your own
   "market" or just post it to your website.

The major con of iPhone is its somewhat obscure programming language: objective-C. Har do grasp if your familiar with Java, C# and other modern languages. Also have to hook up to events using the IDE.

The major con of Android is its different versioning. Sometimes you need to target three different android version just for one app. You also need to keep track of the current used versions here: [Platform Versions](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Android or Iphone the better answer to this particular question is to go for what suits you best. As both these technologiers are growing very rapidly and in demands too as well. So considering that fact, it is very hard to roll out the real thread of conclusion. 
Again as a matter of fact, both these technologier are having a bright future for Sure.

Hope this might be good enough to clear your doubt on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the premium price of iPhones there are probably soon more Android devices than iPhones. However those people who paid a gazillion for their iPhones are more likely to also pay something to get software on those phones and as a result at the moment a lot more money gets made via iPhone apps than via Android apps.

Android has real multitasking with background processes while the iPhone hasn't.